# How to dynamically change theme of angular application

Tags: javascript, typescript, primeng, angular15

I want to change the theme of my angular application dynamically. I am using the Babylon template (primeNG). Is there a way to change the whole theme of the project by selecting the theme from the dropdown?

eg. I have a default theme added in my angular.json file. Now after selection of a different theme from dropdown the theme should change

Comment: You can achieve this by replacing the stylesheets.